# Is it possible to set an expectation of zero interactions with a mock using JMock

Tags: jmock

I am new to JMock, however I have used Mockito before.

I want to assert that a mock has not been used during one of my tests. In Mockito I would use verifyZeroInteractions.

Is there an equivalent in JMock, or do I have to check each of the declared methods?

I am using JMock 2.5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an equivalent:

```
mockery.checking(new Expectations() {{
    never(mockObject);
}});
```

If you want to check that **a specific method** has not been called on your mock:

```
mockery.checking(new Expectations() {{
    never(mockObject).yourSpecificMethod();
}});
```

(And well done for using `JMock`, that's my favourite mocking framework)

Comment: Thanks - I'm actually doing a comparison of Mockito and JMock at the moment.

Comment: and just to clarify, in jMock the default is that all interactions must be declared. It will reject any unexpected (or un-allowed) interactions).